# A modified version of minimum cost flow with fixed source and destination pair

Tags: algorithm, graph, max-flow, network-flow

I am trying to solve a modified instance of the minimum cost flow problem with a directed graph. Specifically, the source and destination pairs are fixed and each edge has a unit cost but a finite capacity. I want to minimize sum(flow)/edge. I have two queries related to this:

1. If each flow takes one path from source to destination, how should I proceed? One solution could be to use a shortest path algorithm (e.g. Dijkstra) but only considering the path which could altogether accommodate the flow. This could be done iteratively solving for each flow and updating the edge capacities each time. I reviewed the literature related to min-cost and max-flow problems, all of them assume that any commodity can flow from any source to any destination (consider demand and supplies of a same type of commodity). My problem is unique is that it contains fixed source and destination pair. Is there an an algorithm for this specific case?
2. If I consider splitting the flows, i.e. each flow can take more than one path, what could be the solution?

Comment: Is the desired value of the flow given as part of the input?

Comment: Yes, the desired flow of the input, i.e. the demand is given

Comment: How does this question relate to http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/66162/755?  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.  Also, what do you mean by "minimize sum(flow)/edge"?  What exactly is the objective function you are trying to minimize?

Comment: Yes sure, wasn't aware of the rules. I deleted the other one. The objective function is to collectively minimize the amount of flows on all edges. Essentially it means for each flow to use minimum amount of edges (boils down to the shortest path). But for multiple sources and destinations; hence multiple flows.